# is it possible to slow speed when drag with jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

is it possible to slow speed when drag with jQuery UI? i'm trying to find the way, but it doesn't work. when i'm using draggable. it move drag object follow mouse at the same speed(pixel) ex: i move mouse to left 10 px, object will move 10px.

but I want to slow down ex: I move mouse to left 10px, object gonna move only 5px.

I found one useful script :

```
$(function(){
    $("#dragme").draggable({
        drag: function(event, ui) {

        // change this multiplier to go faster
        // you may have to do some flooring if you use
        // non integer values
        var mult = 3;

        var $dragme = $(event.target);

        ui.position.top = ui.position.top*mult;
        ui.position.left = ui.position.left*mult;

        $dragme.css({
            top: ui.position.top,
            left: ui.position.left
        });
        }
    });
});
```

there's one problem of this when I start to drag second time, object is moving back to ui.position.top*mult position (it doesn't start form mouse pointer).

How can i do to fix this issue? or can't do with jQuery UI?

Thanks

Comment: You may have to change your event handler type.. check here: http://jsfiddle.net/Jjgmz/1/ do you still see your issue?

Comment: if its using the native jquery animation method, you might be able to hack wherever thats implemented and multiply the delay by 2.  Seems like a tedious solution though....